# Accessing data via Apex from a relationship SOQL

Tags: apex, soql

Can someone tell me how I can access the data from child object via Apex from a relationship SOQL ?

This is my SOQL

```
SELECT Opportunity.Id, Opportunity.Max_Loan_Amount__c, (SELECT Application__c.Id, Application__c.Loan_Amount__c FROM Opportunity.Applications__r) FROM Opportunity WHERE Max_Loan_Amount__c > 0
```

Opportunity is the parent and Application__c is the child.

This is the screenshot from my dev console and as you can see it returns only one record.

[image]

Any pointers or links would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access like below

```
List<Opportunity> oppsList = SELECT Opportunity.Id, Opportunity.Max_Loan_Amount__c, 
 (SELECT Id,Loan_Amount__c FROM Opportunity.Applications__r) 
    FROM Opportunity WHERE Max_Loan_Amount__c > 0

    //For each opportunity
    for(Opportunity opp:oppsList){
         //checking applications list size 
         if(opp.Applications__r.size()>0){
            //looping thru each application
            for(Application__c app:opp.Applications__r){
                 //access application info using app.Id, app.Name here
            }
         }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use the Relationship name to specify the child object in the SOQL inside APEX.

```
List<Opportunity> oppsList = SELECT Opportunity.Id, Opportunity.Max_Loan_Amount__c, 
 (SELECT Id,Loan_Amount__c FROM Opportunity.Applications__r) 
FROM Opportunity WHERE Max_Loan_Amount__c > 0
```

and then when you want to access the child object list, you can use

```
oppsList[index].Applications__r[index]
```